# R Code levenshteinSim() function: comparing two columns in data

Tags: r, record-linkage

I am trying to get a comparison score for two columns in R data frame.
I use library RecordLinkage and tried to apply `levenshteinSim()` function.
The ideas is to get a similar results to

```
levenshteinSim("GR 7G SOLID LEGGING", "GEORGE OPP SOLID LEGGING")

[1] 0.7083333,
```

but comparing column to column.
Tried to use it as follows:

```
gw$test<-levenshteinSim(gw$ITEM_DESCRIPTION, gw$ITEM_SIGNING_DESCRIPTION)
```

where `gw` is my data frame.
However I get the error:

> Error in nchar(str1) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector

Is there any way to apply this function to two columns instead of two actual vectors?
I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

please check the class of your both columns. It should be "character". And if it is not then use `as.character()` for both of them. For eg:

```
gw$ITEM_DESCRIPTION<- as.character(gw$ITEM_DESCRIPTION)
```